# Ruby check if it's october to display pink logo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'd like to use a different logo for breast cancer awareness month (October)...I'd also like the logo to be tested using params so I can ensure it's working up to snuff before October.  Clearly doing something wrong!

Controller:

```
def breast_cancer_logo_month
  if params[:breast_cancer_logo_month] || Time.current.month = 10
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

view:

```
<% if breast_cancer_logo_month  %>
  #breast cancer logo
<% else %>
  #standard logo
<% end %>
```

Comment: change `Time.current.month = 10` to `Time.current.month == 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your breast_cancer_logo_month is wrong. You are using a simple equal when you need two. One equal will try override `Time.current.month` value which will raise an error.
Plus if you return true or false in a condition, you can just return the condition. And you can add a ? to the method name too.

```
def breast_cancer_logo_month?
  !!params[:breast_cancer_logo_month] || Time.current.month == 10
end

<% if breast_cancer_logo_month? %>
  #breast cancer logo
<% else %>
  #standard logo
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick re!!!! The method goes in a controller right? Getting undefined method `breast_cancer_logo_month?'

Comment: GOT IT! Had to add it as a  helper_method  :breast_cancer_logo_month?

Comment: your `breast_cancer_logo_month?` should be in the helper, not the controller.